# Action method was not found on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Despite a ton of questions similar to this one, none seem relevant, so

I have an action with this signature

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOrder(PizzaOrder pizza, Guid? id){
    ...
}
```

I am trying to submit a form with a button. I have verified that the button sends a POST to

```
https://my/controller/url/SaveOrder?id=...
```

It also appears that the PizzaOrder data is being posted correctly.

But, my action never gets hit. Instead, MVC throws an exception

```
A public action method 'SaveOrder' was not found on controller
'Controllers.PizzaController'.
```

Why?

Comment: can you post your view with the actionlink/submitbutton?

Comment: Please show the actual URL.

Comment: Shouldn't it be public ActionResult SaveOrder(Guid? id), check your routes

Comment: Show us your routes and url you're calling

Answer (score 3):

POST does not send **form** data in the URL querystring.

Comment: And, it won't hit the method if it can't identify that it's the correct one - there needs to be a "pizza" (with appropriately bound fields) in the form as well.

Answer (score 2):

There can only be one cause and that's exactly what its saying. The url is wrong. To test this, use the browser developer tools and check to see what the url the page is posting to and what the actual url is. Controller vs PizzaController? or.... you are doing a GET to a POST. POST doesn't have SaveOrder?id=.

Answer (score 1):

The request you are trying is GET not POST as you are passing parameters with Querystring ?id=... Try after removing `[HttpPost]` attribute

Comment: Seems to be, but that's changing response like removing attribute can resolve the problem... :)